# How to wrap the Gutenberg editor in a custom React component?

Tags: block-editor

#### Motivation

For the custom Gutenberg blocks I'm creating, I'd like to use React components from a third party UI library. These components depend on a shared `ContextProvider` being available somewhere high up in the component tree.

#### Problem

How to wrap the Gutenberg editor (within WordPress, if that makes any difference) in a `ContextProvider`, or any other component for that matter?

Comment: Please check following, may be it will be helpful for you.
https://torquemag.io/2018/11/sharing-react-components-with-gutenberg/

Comment: @AshishOdich While a nice post, it doesn't explain how to wrap the Gutenberg editor with arbitrary React components.

Comment: These won't solve the problem for you, but they might provide some helpful direction: https://github.com/WordPress/pattern-directory/pull/26, https://github.com/WordPress/pattern-directory/pull/27